# React Three Fiber Canvas Stretches its Parent and Becomes Unresponsive

Tags: reactjs, canvas, three.js, tailwind-css, react-three-fiber

I have had this problem across multiple projects with `react-three-fiber`

below is the structure of my project

```js
    <div className='p-4 flex flex-col h-screen bg-primaryBackground-dark'>
      <div className='flex flex-1 items-center'>
        <div className='bg-secondaryBackground-dark h-full grow-[2] rounded-lg shadow-inner '>
          <Canvas>
            <gridHelper />
            <axesHelper position={[0, 0.01, 0]} />
            <CameraControls />
          </Canvas>
        </div>

        <div className='bg-secondaryBackground-dark h-full grow-1 rounded-lg shadow-inner '></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am using tailwindcss in the project, you can probably already see that. If you aren't familiar `grow-[2]` is equivalent to `flex-grow:2` and `grow-1` is equivalent to `flex-grow:1`.

Here's the problem, if I don't put `Canvas` in the project, the page looks like it should. A `div` on the left takes 2/3rd of the screen and a `div` on the right takes the remaining 1/3rd. But when I put `Canvas` in the project as shown above the left `div` stretches to take all of the available space. It also becomes unresponsive: if I try to reduce the size of the window the size of the canvas does not decrease but if I try to increase the window size the size of the `Canvas` increases.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem was.

By default, `flex` sets it's min width to be equal to the size of its content. Once the `Canvas` is created the min width of the flex changes to the size of the `Canvas`

just setting `minWidth` to 0 on the `div` that contains the `Canvas` solves this issue